# Resource requests through snakemake --resources vs. cluster submission

Tags: python, resources, cluster-computing, snakemake

I am hoping to clear up some confusion I have about the snakemake resources keyword ([documented here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources)). If I am running jobs on a cluster, does this parameter make an actual memory request from the cluster scheduler for a specific job? Or, does it only make sure snakemake won't submit jobs if they would exceed the resource limits specified from the commandline.

I am primarily confused because in my snakemake job logs, it says I only have 100mb memory allocated as resources. But, in my cluster submission command (eg: qsub) I am requesting a couple gb of memory and the jobs do not run out of memory (which I predict they should if there was only 100mb of allocated memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is broken, but I'll answer with "it depends".  Specifically on your snakemake version and how you are integrating with the cluster.  If you use the `--cluster` option, you have access to your resource object in the script.  I use slurm so my argument looks like `sbatch --mem={resources.mem_mb}M ...`.  I've not made it to version 8 yet, so I'll defer to someone else on that.

The amount reported in the logs is probably the default, and if you hard code in your memory to qsub it won't matter.